# Python3: Al usar super() en el método del padre, el MRO del hijo se sigue respetando (curioso comportamiento del MRO)

Tags: python, python-3.x, herencia

Publico aquí un comportamiento curioso que he observado en el uso de `super()` en casos de herencia múltiple y de varios niveles en Python3. Observad el siguiente código:

```
class Z:
    def metodo(self): 
        print("Método Z")

class A (Z): 
    def metodo(self): 
        print("Método A")
        super().metodo()

class B (Z): 
    def metodo(self): 
        print("Método B")

class C(A,B): pass

ObjetoC = C()
ObjetoC.metodo()
```

Da como resultado:

```
Método A
Método B
```

Por lo que parece que la instrucción `super().metodo()` ejecutada dentro de A, pero evocada desde el "hijo" C, no hace referencia al "padre " de A (que es Z) sino, al otro "padre" de C, que es B. Esto es un poco inesperado.

Ahora observad que pasa si agregamos la misma instrucción `super().metodo()` dentro de B:

```
class Z:
    def metodo(self): 
        print("Método Z")

class A (Z): 
    def metodo(self): 
        print("Método A")
        super().metodo()

class B (Z): 
    def metodo(self): 
        print("Método B")
        super().metodo()

class C(A,B): pass


ObjetoC = C()
ObjetoC.metodo()

print(C.mro())
```

El resultado es:

```
Método A
Método B
Método Z
```

Recién se llama al método del "abuelo" Z, pareciera cuando finalmente se han acabado los "padres" de C que podrían ejecutar dicha instrucción.

Este último comportamiento si que es esperado, e incluso bastante deseable.

Calculo que la razón es que en todo momento, el MRO de C se sigue respetando, incluso cuando se ejecuta una instrucción en alguno de sus "padres" o "ancestros". Echemos una mirada a dicho MRO

```
>>> print(C.mro())
[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.Z'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Parece que concuerda con la idea. Si estuviera equivocado o sabéis de alguna otra razón, os agradeceré me lo comentéis en una respuesta. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás malinterpretando lo que `super` realmente hace, no busca de acuerdo al MRO de la clase en la que es llamado, busca de acuerdo al MRO de la clase del objeto.

Empecemos por el principio, debemos recordar que `super` no retorna un objeto realmente, retorna un objeto proxy que delega las llamadas al método correcto. Pero más importante aún, **la indirección se calcula en tiempo de ejecución**.

Además, debemos tener en cuenta que:

```
super().metodo()
```

es equivalente a:

```
super(__class__, <primer_argumento_del_método>)
```

por lo que en `A.metodo` es realmente:

```
super(A, self).metodo()
```

de hecho, en Pyhon 2 (que no disponía de `__class__`) había que llamarlo así.

> La celda `__class__` se genera solo si la clase hace uso de `super` o del método `__class__`

No es trivial ésto, de ambos componentes depende cómo `super` busca y resuelve el método.

- El primer argumento indica a partir de que entrada en el MRO buscar. Se buscará en la clase a la derecha en la posición de dicho argumento en la lista MRO.
- Es el segundo argumento el que determina el MRO a usar. Típicamente es `self` (métodos de instancia) o `cls` (en el caso de métodos de clase). El método además será ligado a dicho objeto.

El primer componente, la clase dónde se llama a `super` (`A` en éste caso) es estático, depende del código fuente sin más. El segundo (la referencia a la instancia,`self`, en éste caso), es variable.

Traducido, `super(A, self).metodo()` le dice a `super` algo como:

> Búscame **en `C.mro`** la primera clase con un método de instancia llamado `metodo` y empieza a **buscar a partir de `A`**.

Es decir, como tenemos como MRO de `C` (clase de `ObjetoC`):

```
[<class 'C'>, <class 'A'>, <class 'B'>, <class 'Z'>, <class 'object'>]
```

`super` busca `A`:

```
[<class 'C'>, <class 'A'>, <class 'B'>, <class 'Z'>, <class 'object'>]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

pero `A` no le interesa, le interesa la siguiente clase en la lista que implemente el método `metodo` (valga la redundancia...) y la encuentra pronto, es `B`.

Por lo tanto, lo que hace el primer ejemplo es:

- Llamar al método `metodo` de `C`.
- Como no lo implementa se recurre a MRO y la primera clase con el método es `A`, se ejecuta.
- Al ejecutar el método se llega a `super().metodo()`, se procede como se ha descrito y `super` retorna un objeto proxy que nos permite llamar al método de `B`.
- Se llama a `B.metodo`.
- Como el método en `B` no llama al método del padre, se acaba la historia aquí.

Cuando se implementa `super` en una subclase y se pretende que exista cooperación, hay que seguir siempre unas normas básicas:

- Todas las superclases deben también usar `super`.
- Cada llamada al método en la cadena debe recibir los argumentos que necesite y pasar el resto al siguiente.

tu segundo ejemplo por lo tanto si es una implementación correcta de herencia múltiple con cooperación. La clave está en que la historia anterior no termina en `B.metodo`, como `B.metodo` hace uso de también de `super`, se busca la siguiente clase a partir de `B` en el MRO de `C` que implementa `metodo`, que es `Z` y se llama.

Puede parecer extraño, pero `super` tiene un potencial enorme a pesar de históricamente haber sido malentendido y infrautilizado. Junto al MRO que es determinista (C3 superclass linearization) `super` no solo permite resolver el problema del diamante en clases de nuevo estilo (tu código es un buen ejemplo del problema del diamante y cómo lo resuelve Python por cierto), permite alterar el MRO en tiempo de ejecución, inyección de dependencias, el uso e implementación de mixins, interfaces, clases abstractas, etc.

Tanto es así, que la herencia múltiple en Python sin `super` es a veces imposible o al menos muy complicada, en cambio entendiendo el MRO y cómo `super` actúa se pueden conseguir comportamientos muy complejos e interesantes, frameworks como Django se apoyan enormemente en ésto.

Si el inglés no es un gran problema, Raymond Hettinger, desarrollador del núcleo de CPython y miembro de la PSF (además de usuario de SO ʘ‿ʘ) dio una interesante conferencia en la PyCon de 2015 en Montreal sobre `super`:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo